# Getting youtube links from post_content not working

Tags: youtube

I am trying to retrieve youtube links from post_content but it does not work..

```
function get_yts() {
      $query_args = array(
        's' => 'youtube.com/watch?v=',
      );

      $posts = get_posts( $query_args );
      foreach ($posts as $p) {
        $matches = array();
        preg_match('|http://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)|', $p->post_content, $matches);
        echo '$xxmatches: ' . $matches . ' -> '. $p->post_content;
      }
    }
```

result show be an empty array:

```
$xxmatches: Array
```

what am I doing wrong ?

EDIT:

found better regex which matches really in some editor but not in here:

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!
$text = '<!-- wp:core-embed/youtube {"url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycsODGR5IDQ","type":"video","providerNameSlug":"youtube","className":"wp-embed-aspect-4-3 wp-has-aspect-ratio"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-embed-youtube wp-block-embed is-type-video is-provider-youtube wp-embed-aspect-4-3 wp-has-aspect-ratio"><div class="wp-block-embed__wrapper">
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycsODGR5IDQ
</div></figure>';

$matches = array();
preg_match('/http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?v=|\.be\/)([\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)?[\w\?‌​=]*)?/', $text, $text);
echo '$xxmatches: ' . sizeof($matches);
```

shows me 0 size..

Comment: Are you sure that your search is returning results? What happens when you type `$posts = get_posts( $query_args ); var_dump($posts); exit;`? `youtube.com/watch?v=` contains a couple of special characters namely `/`, `?`, & `=` which could be filtered out or escaped when the search terms are searched for by WordPress.

Comment: you can't echo an array.  `echo '$xxmatches: ' . implode(', ', $matches)  . ' -> '. $p->post_content;`

Comment: Also you need to escape special characters in your regex `https?:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)`

Comment: This code also won’t match any https YouTube embeds, which I believe is standard these days.

Comment: @jacob just added the `s?` to that string

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is working code:

```
function get_yts() {
  $query_args = array(
    's' => 'youtube.com/watch?v=',
  );

  $posts = get_posts( $query_args );
  foreach ($posts as $p) {
    $input_line = $p->post_content;
    $output_array = array();
    preg_match('/http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?v=|\.be\/)([\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)?[\w\?‌​=]*)?/', $input_line, $output_array);
    print_r($output_array);
  }
}
```